# Communicating between nested child components in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

It won't take you long to realise that I am probably out of my depth here. I am not only new to React.js but also to ES6 and so please be gentle with your answers...

Here goes.

I am using a component to build a form input:

```
const Input = (props) => {
    return(
        <input ... />
    )
}
```

I have a component which I use to construct HTML around any of the basic form elements that I give it.

```
const InputWrap = (props) => {
    return(
        <div class="input-wrap" ...>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Which allows me to do something like this...

```
const Input = (props) => {
    return(
        <InputWrap>
            <input ... />
        </InputWrap>
    )
}
```

What I would like to do is to add a character counting component to the mix:

```
const InputWrap = (props) => {
    return(
        <div class="input-wrap" ... >
            {children} // which is the HTML input
            {props.maxValue && <CharCounter />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

So here is my problem...

The `<CharCounter />` needs to be notified of any changes happening to the `<input />` and update it's internal state.

The `<input />` and the `<CharCounter />` are siblings and children of the `<InputWrap />` and so, from what I can gather, I need a method inside `<InputWrap />` which ties an `onChange` of the `<input />` and some method that will update the state within the `<CharCount />` component.

I am at a loss as to how I go about adding a callback as the `<input onChange={doSomething} />` is in the form `{children}` by the time it comes in contact with the `<CharCount />` once inside the `<InputWrap />`...

Where am I going wrong here? I'm starting to think it was way back at the beginning...

Answer (score 1):

There are two typical ways of communication between siblings:

1. You use the InputWrapper as an DataContainer
2. You use a Data Flow library like flux or redux (which is a lot more complex, especially for this case)

For the 1. you need, as you correctly noticed, an onChange handler for the input component, which is a function defined in the  Component and which is passed to the input. If your input component is an own component and not the native component you will need to pass the onChange prop to the native input.

The function in the  Component takes the input, counts the chars and sets an internal state variable with setState({ charCount: #CountValue#}). And then you can pass the state variable to the CharCount Component with

One Important thing to mention: You are using stateless components and therefore you will need to change your InputWrap to a normal react component

```
class InputWrap extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

Hope this will give you the right direction.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for that. Like I said below, I want to keep this out of Redux as it seems like a sledgehammer to crack a walnut. I've been backwards and forwards so many times I needed to make sure I was on the right path. I'll return soon hopefully with my results.

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent solution that is like redux but has a different architecture and api is  https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react.

You can use the inject HOC to inject shared state to any react component in your application.

Comment: Thanks... I wanted to keep this component away from our Redux store as it seems unnecessary to have it keeping track of such menial data. Additionally, I cannot bare to think of yet more to learn... Thanks anyway.